# Modify Django CreateView to include Admin like "Add Another" Button

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-crispy-forms

For the most part, Django's CreateView works fine for everything I need. However, I'd like to put an "Add Another" button next to every model select dropdown element across my application, like in the admin interface.

Is there a good way for me to modify the form created by CreateView to include this button?

I'm using Django 1.8 and django-crispy-forms.

UPDATE

I'd like to make the change happen somewhere before the template since I can currently use a very generic template to deal with all my models. I'd like to just use `{{ form }}` that way I don't have to define a new template for each model.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is what you need but you can add a button to your template and then process the information adding method post in your CreateView.

```
MyVista(Createview)
    template_name = "mytemplate.html"

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == ´POST´
            pass
```

Comment: I'd like to use a more DRY solution than this. I've got lots of models which all need the same functionality change.